# Hide content not containing select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I would like to filter the shown content by country, using a select box. The page initially shows all content, but when a country is selected, everything that *doesn't* match that value is hidden by adding a CSS class.

This is my relevant code so far:

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYCy9/)

**HTML:**

```
<select name="filter" id="filter">
    <option value="" disabled selected></option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
<div class="media">
    <p>blah blah blah France blah blah</p>
</div>
<div class="media">
    <p>blah blah blah Germany blah blah</p>
</div>
<div class="media">
    <p>blah blah blah Germany blah blah</p>
</div>
<div class="media">
    <p>blah blah blah UK blah blah</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#filter').change(function () {
    var country = $('#filter').val();
    $('.media').each(function () {
        if ($('.media').find(country)) {

        } else {
            $('.media').addClass('hidden');
        }
    })
});
```

I have little experience with jQuery/JavaScript, but I've investigated and think I need to loop through all the matching content "blocks" with `each()`, each time looking for the relevant content with `find()`, but I don't know enough to get this working. My code currently does nothing whatsoever.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you intending to search through the text content of the elements to find the country name? If so it doesn't seem the best solution. What if the English paragraph is 'In the UK the currency is the Pound, meanwhile in Germany it is the Euro' and the user selects Germany from the dropdown?

Comment: Each box is basically a profile overview, containing a photo, age, residing country, and previous countries. It would be useful to not just search people residing in France, for instance, but people who have previously been there. I think searching the whole `.media` `div` is going to be the best option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this:

```
$('#filter').change(function () {
   var country = $('#filter').val();
   $('.media').hide();
   $('.media:contains('+ country.toLowerCase() +')').show();
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NYCy9/2/)

---

Or:

```
$('#filter').change(function () {
   var country = $('#filter').val();
   $('.media').addClass('hidden');
   $('.media:contains(' + country.toLowerCase() + ')').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NYCy9/3/)

Comment: This was the simplest code to use, and whilst all of them worked (thank you), this is the method I have implemented. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Normally filtering is done based on the divisions or classes and the text in them not alone text...But since every problem has a solution,
Here's yours.

http://jsfiddle.net/hardeepmehta/NYCy9/4/

`$('#filter').change(function () {
    var country = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var elements = [];
    $('.media').each(function(){
      if($(this).text().indexOf(country)==-1)
      {
       $(this).hide(); 
      }
      else
      {
       $(this).show();
       }
    });
});`

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#filter').change(function () {
    var country = $('#filter').val().toLowerCase();
    $('.media').each(function () {
        if ($(':contains(' + country + ')', this).length) {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
    })
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NYCy9/1/)**

Comment: i don't think loop is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use custom `data-*` attributes to differentiate between countries:

```
<div class="media" data-country="UK">
    <p>blah blah blah UK blah blah</p>
</div>
```

And then simply match and hide:

```
$('#filter').change(function () {
    var country = this.value;
    $(".media").addClass("hidden");
    $(".media [data-country=" + country + "]").addClass("show");
});
```